# Copy Array formula in Excel 2013

Tags: arrays, excel

I have an array formula to pull data that meets a certain criteria.  I have copied the formula and it appears the array function copied over correctly - however - only the first row displays correctly.  After that there are some duplicates and some records that should be pulled that are not.

Formula - `=IFERROR(INDEX(Vol!C$4:C$2000,SMALL(IF(Vol!$B4:$B2000=Train!$A$2,ROW(Vol!C$4:C$2000)-ROW(Vol!$C$4)+1),ROWS(Vol!C$4:Vol!C4))),"")`
Please let me know what other info you would need. Thanks!

Comment: In which cell have you entered the formula ??

Comment: My best guess is that you intended to have `$` after each `B` in the formula. I could be wrong.